# Is storing data into well structured file system faster than querying a big database table?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, file

I have a database table of 133,000,000 rows. My database data won't change like for a year, so I don't need any inserts into this database nor anything I just need to fetch data from it. Like for example fetch 60 rows that have country Australia. This is being slow taking into consideration the amount of data there is. My question is, is it better to store my data into well indexed files. Like for example Make folders of all letters and digits.

So will have 35 folders A,B,C,D,E,....,7,8,9 then in each of these folders there is a folder for countries, cities etc... so Australia goes in A -> Countries -> Australia then inside of Australia folder I have all the Australia data from my DB separated into files.

Will this be faster for php to fetch than just querying the table of 133,000,000 rows?

Comment: Always do your own tests... ;)

Comment: I know, but I want to have an idea before putting the database into files than discovering it was worthless.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on how you want to query the data. Filtering it like that by country will work if the only querying you want to do is by country - what if you want to query by city, or by state? Data for cities where population is >5 million? That's when a well-structured well-indexed database will win, every time.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I don't need to do or's there are no complex queries it is always like get me all rows for this city, or get me all rows for this state not more. I'll keep the database in all cases for such transactions but basically will move the fetching of big amounts of data for 1 single condition to reading from files.

Comment: I would cache the results of specific queries in RAM. That will be fast. Depending on what your application does, you may want to have that set of queries (rows where country = x?) cache in application "start up".

Comment: so basically what we're saying here is: don't go the files way :)

Answer (score 0):

You can divide your main table to sub-tables based on country names. for example `table_canada` for all rows from country `canada` and `table_usa` for all rows from country `usa` and so on. Then if you want to fetch data from them, your code should be something like this:

```
$country = "canada"; //or from a form like $country = $_POST['country'];
$table = "table_" . $country;
$query = "SELECT * from $table ...";
...
```

Comment: hmmm idea. making a table for each country city state .... will result in lot of tables.

what if I separate them by letters like for example countries_a, this will contain all countries that begin with a with the one field of data I want so for example

countries_a will be:

id - country - name
1  - Australia - XXX
2  - Argentina - YYY

and so on. I think this will make my data faster to access.

Opinions please...

Comment: yes , that would be a good approach. it was just a suggestion. But Do not make it too complicated

Comment: very late for the party, But this "sub table" thing is actually called partitions, no need to create a new table for each country, you can rather partition by country, this has the same effect